# In what case does a Coil with Current flowing through it NOT produce a Magnetic Field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

According to what I've studied, when Current flows through a Coil, a Magnetic field is produced.

Recently, I've been told that there is a case in which Current flows through a Coil **Without** producing a Magnetic field.

I've searched everywhere, but I haven't been able to find this situation.

**So; What is the case in which current flows through a Coil without producing a Magnetic Field?**

PS: Please Strike out the idea that the case doesn't exist; the one that told me of it is a Physics Professor with a wide array of knowledge. I lost contact with him though; otherwise I would've just asked him...

Comment: Side note: Coil = Electromagnetic Coil

Comment: Do you mean a solenoid?

Comment: The case doesn't exist for the usual definitions of the words you are using (although one could construct something as weird as a coil for neutral currents that do, indeed, not produce magnetic fields because they are producing other fields, instead). You asking for it to be ruled out doesn't change the correct answer, neither do references to physics professors that you can't identify.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's a very common technology. See my answer below

Comment: @Jaywalker I mean Electromagnetic Coil in general; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_coil

Comment: I thought a magnetic field was created by a CHANGING electric field. In that "case", any coil with a DC current would not be creating a magnetic field. Getting the DC current to start with? That's a different "case".

Comment: Could the coil be insulated to reduce the intensity or eliminate  the electromagnetic field created by the current?

Comment: @AlanCampbell a magnetic field is created by a moving charge which is present in both dc and ac current. However the rate of change of flux density does have an effect.

Comment: It is possible to use allows like mu-metal or permalloy to "insulate" magnetic fields

Comment: Would an insulated coil be a plausible answer?

Comment: @Joel Sadly, that doesn't work out. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet Insulated Coil does produce a Magnetic field :/ That info is also available here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_coil#Windings_and_taps

Comment: Also, according to what I've tried; DC makes the EM-Coil produce a normal Magnetic Field, and AC makes it produce a Magnetic Field that constantly changes direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a [Bifilar or Caduceus Coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifilar_coil) Which contains two closely spaced, parallel windings. Most often used for constructing wire wound resistors in order to minimize both inductance and stray magnetic fields

Comment: But such a coil does produce a magnetic field between the windings.

Comment: Very interesting answer... but as CuriousOne commented, that's the problem. Apart from that, your answer is most likely what my Professor meant. Thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: The fact of magnetic field between the windings is trivially true, since you can reduce the wire size to a one dimensional flow of electrons. Right next to each moving electron there is a magnetic field, even if there is also another traveling in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It seems like all the answers seem to be pointing to this same case, so I guess I'll mark this as the best.

Answer (score 4):

The person you've been talking too is probably imagining a physical case in which each clockwise coil is matched with a counter-clockwise one. This is probably easiest to realize by wrapping once along a solenoid one was and then wrapping an over-layer in the reversed sense.

If the matching is good and the coil density is high and uniform the resulting field will be net zero at all places farther from the wires than the spacing between the corresponding wraps.

---

Arguably each stretch of the coil *does* produce a field, but they cancel each other out almost everywhere.

Comment: Almost everywhere does not mean that the magnetic field is zero... indeed, it's actually quite strong right between the two adjacent windings... the total field energy is simply small because the effective volume is small. I doubt that a serious physics professor would make such an example, at least in the naive way the OP is formulating it.

Comment: Well, I certainly wouldn't phrase it the way the OP has done, but I think that it is a good illustration of the superposition principle applied to magnetic fields.

Comment: I am going out on a limb here, but I don't think that a+(-a)=0 is a sufficient criterion for superposition. Even mathematically one would need at least associativity and commutativity, I believe, to describe a classical field that obeys a superposition law. The naive statement is certainly 100% false, as far as I can tell, as long as we keep to charged currents and electromagnetic fields and as long as we respect physically possible boundary condition.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only time would be when the coil was wound one way and then the opposite was with the same number of turns so that the net magnetic field produced was zero. In fact the coils would have to be wound particularly carefully and the cancelling would probably not be perfect everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

There is another case besides the one mentioned in other answers: In inductors and transformers, an internal magnetic field is created, but there is a closed magnetic loop which means that the magnetic field does not escape. Besides avoiding creating interference, it is also desirable to prevent escape of the magnetic field for efficiency reasons. The best type of transformer in this respect is the toroidal transformer, due to its circular symmetry.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor

As others have mentioned, this construction is not suitable for wirewound resistors because of the inductance. Wirewound resistors frequently have coils wound in opposite directions to ensure a pure resistance without any undesired inductance.

Another device worth mentioning is the "humbucking" type of guitar pickup. This is a design with two oppositely wound coils close together, which avoids picking up interference from the ambient magnetic field. It's not normal to pass a current through such a pickup, but if you did the magnetic field produced would be present but extremely localised (due to the small spacing between the two coils.) It's essential that there some localised interaction to be able to pick up the magnetic field of the string. The closer the coils are together, the smaller the area of influence. It's not possible to have a guitar pickup in which one coil is co-wound with the other as then it would not interact with the string at all (and would produce no field when a current was passed through it.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbucker

Comment: Transformers... seems pretty interesting. A Magnetic Field _is_ created, but only an internal one... I think it's a good answer, but first I think I'll look for an answer that doesn't involve creating a Magnetic Field altogether.

Comment: One more thing... That last part of Humbucking: "(and would produce no field when a current was passed through it.)" If I understood correctly, what occurs there is the same case as what's been mentioned in previous answers, Bifilar Coil... Or did I misunderstand? Also, Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @MaChao The closer together the two coils of a humbucking pickup are, the smaller the area of influence is. If the two coils coincide exactly, we have the same case as in the other answers (a coil wound equally in both directions.) this would produce no magnetic field if a current was applied, but it would also be useless as a pickup. The coils have to have the right spacing: wide enough to be able to detect the string, but narrow enough to reject as much as possible the ambient electromagnetic noise (composed mainly of 50Hz / 60Hz mains electricity hum.)

Comment: Makes sense now, thank you. So, the case in which "No Magnetic Field is produced" continues to be Bifilar Coil.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing i can imagine is a coil constituted by one wire which one half is coiled clockwise and the other half is coiled counterclockwise. So one part produces a magnetic field in one direction and the other part produces the field in the opposite direction.

This might be obvious, but I really cannot think in any other possibility for this, unless the wire is not in any normal condition (e.G.: extreme temperatures, or other extreme conditions involved).

Comment: Extreme conditions... Is there perhaps an extreme condition that would prevent the coil from producing a Magnetic field? Just thinking for possible answers... Thanks for answering by the way.